# DynamoDB Last Evaluated Key Expiration?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

My application ingests data from a 3rd party REST API which is backed by DynamoDB.  The results are paginated and thus I page forward by passing the last evaluated key to each subsequent request.

My question is does the last evaluated key have a shelf life?  Does it ever expire?

Let's say I query the REST API and then decide to stop.  If I save the last evaluated key, can pick up exactly where I left off **30 days** later?  Would that last evaluated key still work and return the correct next page based on where I left off previously?

Answer (score 13):

You shouldn't think of the last evaluated key like a "placeholder" or a "bookmark" in a result set from which to resume paused iteration.

You should think of it more like a "start from" place marker. An example might help. Let's say you have a table with a hash key `userId` and a range key `timestamp`. The range key `timestamp` will provide an ordering for your result set. Say your table looked like this:

```
user ID | Timestamp
   1    |  123
   1    |  124
   1    |  125 
   1    |  126
```

In this order, when you query the table for all of the records for `userId` `1`, you'll get the records back in the order they're listed above, or ascending order by timestamp. If you wanted them back in descending order, you'd use Dyanmo DB's `scanIndexForward` flag to indicate to order them "newest to oldest" or in descending order by timestamp.

Now, suppose there were a lot more than 4 items in the table and it would take multiple queries to return all of the records with a `userId` of one. Well, you wouldn't want to have to keep getting pages and pages back, so you can tell Dynamo DB where to start by giving it the last evaluated key. Say the last result for the previous query was the record with `userId = 1` and `timestamp = 124`. You tell Dynamo in your query that that was the last record you got, and it will start your next result set with the record that has `userId = 1` and `timestamp = 125`.

So the last evaluated key isn't something that "expires," it's a way for you to communicate to Dynamo which records you want it to return based on records that you've already processed, displayed to the user, etc.